# How to make a list of an array of ints?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, data-structures

I want to have an array of 2 Int32 values, say:

```
 Int32 x
 Int32 y
```

I want to make a list of these arrays.

- How do I declare and initialize this array and the list?
- How do I access the members of the list once I've populated it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to turn an array into a data structure that it is not by storing values in sequence.  Don't do this.  Learn how to use more advanced data structures to your advantage.

You mention a `Point` type with an `x` and `y` value.  How about a class instead?

```
class Point
{
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;
    public Point( int x, int y )
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Now you can create instances of your new type and add them to a list, simplifying the entire process and also making sure you don't slip up down the road and add an `x` to your array where a `y` should be.

```
List<Point> ls = new List<Point>();
ls.Add( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
ls.Add( new Point( 10, 10 ) );
ls.Add( new Point( 100, 100 ) );
```

Anyway, it would be a good idea to read up on how you can create your own data structures in C#.  There are many benefits to learning how to appropriately store your data in a way that is easy to work with.

Comment: Perhaps a `struct` would be more appropriate than a `class` for a point.

Comment: @icktoofay: I was waiting for someone to say that =).  I really didn't want to get into value types versus reference types.  The OP is obviously a beginner.  I thought it best to show as simple an example as possible as he will need to take the next step and learn about this stuff on his own at a much deeper level.

Answer (score 8):

```
List<int[]> l = new List<int[]>();

l.Add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
l.Add(new int[] { 3, 4 });

int a = l[1][0];   // a == 3
```

Comment: If you really are using an x and y for the two integer array. You might use an existing class or create your own. Then you can just use a List<Point> or List<CustomClass>

Answer (score 2):

There is not quite enough information on what you would like. But here a basic example of initializing a generic list of an Int32 array. I hope this helps

```
        Int32 x = 1; 
        Int32 y = 2;

        // example of declaring a list of int32 arrays
        var list = new List<Int32[]> {
            new Int32[] {x, y}
        };

        // accessing x
        list[0][0] = 1;

        // accessing y
        list[0][1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use a list of tuple that contains two int32 only:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> myList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

var item = new Tuple<int, int>(25, 3);

myList[0] = new Tuple<int, int>(20, 9);//acess to list items by index index

myList.Add(item);//insert item to collection

myList.IndexOf(item);//get the index of item

myList.Remove(item);//remove item from collection
```

The benefit from using `List<Tuple<int, int>>` over a second list like `List<List<int, int>>` or `List<int[]>` is that you explicit force list items to be just two integers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two types of arrays.  Multidimensional arrays, and jagged arrays.  You can use either (more on their differences at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).

An example of a jagged array:

```
Int32[][] = new Int32[] { new Int32[] {1,2}, new Int32[] {3,4}};
```

An example of a multidimensional array:

```
Int32[,] = new Int32[,] {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Hoped that help clear things up a bit.  If you meant actual lists, then look at the other answers.